# String variable declaration in windows application

Tags: c#

I declared a string variable in C# like in VS2010 Express in windows application,

```
string strVariable = string.Empty;
//ContextUtil.DeactivateOnReturn = true;           
try
{
XmlDocument xmlSourceDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlSourceDoc.LoadXml(strXmlDocument);
strVariable = xmlSourceDoc.DocumentElement.GetAttribute("attire");
```

While debugging I put `strVariable` to watch,it said like

> The name 'strVariable' does not exist in the current context".

One more thing `xmlSourceDoc.DocumentElement.GetAttribute("attire")` when I put to watch I get results.

what might be the problem ?

Comment: I tried adding string strVariable= string.empty; strVariable="doesn`t work";.Still same problem.

Comment: Where were you, scope-wise, when you added the watch?

Comment: Where are you trying to access `strVariable`? If it's out of scope then you will get that message.

Comment: ReBuild your solution and try. It seems after adding above line your project don't build properly.

Comment: Can you show more code than that single line? You are most likely trying to use that variable outside of its declaration space.

Comment: You need to watch it inside variable scope.

Comment: I'm assuming you debugged *after* the declaration, yes?

Comment: @GrantThomas:After assigning to variable only I put it to watch.

Comment: Have you break-ed into the debugger when trying to perform this watch?

Comment: @spender:what you mean by break-ed?

Comment: Unless you've hit a breakpoint or an exception that the debugger has caught, watching isn't going to show anything. To see variables in the watch, you need to set a breakpoint somewhere where the variable is in scope, allow the debugger to break, then try viewing it.

Comment: @spender:I have put a breakpoint after that line of code.Still same problem.

Answer (score 0):

ReBuild your solution and try.

It seems after adding above line your project don't build properly.

Comment: :I need to debug this.So after adding variable I just press "F5" to start debugging.

Comment: Actually some time it's happen that changes not reflected. So, it's better practice to Build or Rebuild solution after done changes in solution/Project.

Comment: :I tried rebuilding it.Still same problem.No I can`t add anything while debugging it.

Comment: okay. now I can say Delete all files from your output directory and try to rebuild solution again.. Just check your current project dll build time in your output directory. if it' not last build time that means your changes not reflected.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using that variable in your code beyond defining it?  Many times, with unused variables, they get trimmed away by the compiler because you're not doing anything that effects control flow or data state.  Try putting another line that tests if it's == String.Empty and do something with it if so... should trick the compiler to include it.

Comment: "Optimizing away" would only happen in release mode.

Comment: @spender - Depends on settings, but I've seen it many times with default settings when stepping through the debugger.  You're absolutely right that optimizations to improve performance is an aspect of release builds... Perhaps poor choice of verb.  Going with trimmed away.